# REST get How to pass userid and password with each request

Tags: rest

Our application has different roles for each user and only certain users are allowed to query the data. We have to validate user id and password for each request.

I have a simple REST get where the user passes employee id and we return employee data. What is the best way to pass userid and password? Is using userid and password in URL (i.e. @PathParam)  bad idea?

Right now I have it as follows, this will return the employee data for emp id 111 by user u1

https:../MyRestWebService/services/getEmp/u1/encpassword/111

Only https port will be open in the firewall i.e. all requests are always over https and password is always encoded string (we publish how to encode)

thanks

Comment: When you say the password is 'encoded' can you be more specific?

Comment: it will not be readable by human, coded per specification, e.g base64encoded. Note that all communication will be over https and system admin that can look at tcpdump or any such traces will have full access to system, including being able to change user permission, password etc. i.e. security of the password at the server is not a problem. I am thinking more from the client perspective.

Comment: I was more wondering if the password was (public/private key) encrypted. It sounds like 'no', so the password could be decoded by anyone that gets ahold of the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether or not this is a good idea always depends on exactly how you are using it. Passing the password itself will probably raise eyebrows at least, and it could be a serious problem.

Generally, the two approaches are require a login prior to issuing further calls, which mimics what a human user would use the system but requires logic to handle logging in and out on the client side. The second is to use API tokens, which is potentially less secure, but more convenient for automated clients. Note, there's no fundamental reason you can't do both.

Take a look at how github handles API authentication; they actually do both. You can do an OpenAuth authentication to create an authenticated session, which takes the form of a temporary access token used in subsequent requests. You can also create a permanent access token and associate it to the account.

- https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/
- https://developer.github.com/v3/auth/#basic-authentication (see x-oauth-basic variation)

You can also use a framework or built in support for sessions (depending on your server stack) to track authenticated sessions implicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Client will be written by users of our web service and they wanted very simple solution, adding anything like this will increase their work. UserID and passwords are already assigned so they have it. I will just use the post method with json input that will have userid, password and emp id.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, putting username and password in the URI is a bad idea. For starters, it means you can't share the URI without exposing your username and password. Is there some compelling reason you aren't using HTTP Basic Authentication? This seems like the exact case it's designed for.

```
GET https://.../employees/111
```

is a much more correct URI.

Comment: thanks for answering my question. I am new to stackoverflow and it seems it lets me only pick one right answer.